# Event attribute vs. addEventListener - is the attribute capturing?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

When using the Javascript method `addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture])` I'm able to set the `useCapture` flag to true.

If true, `useCapture` indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.

Is the HTML attribute like `onclick="listener();"` capturing by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture.

No, it means the event handler is called during the capture (or target) phase of the event cycle rather than the bubbling (or target) phase. This diagram from [the UI events spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow) does a great job of conveying the three phases of an event:

[image]

> Event attribute vs. addEventListener - is the attribute capturing?

No, when you use the old DOM0 `onxyz`-attribute-style or property-style event handling, it's like using `false` for that `addEventListener` parameter: You're setting a handler for the bubbling (or target) phase, not the capture phase.

Example:

```js
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
var middle = document.getElementById("middle");
var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
hook(outer, false);
hook(outer, true);
outer.onclick = function() {
  console.log("outer: DOM0");
};
hook(middle, false);
hook(middle, true);
middle.onclick = function() {
  console.log("middle: DOM0");
};
hook(inner, false);
hook(inner, true);
inner.onclick = function() {
  console.log("inner: DOM0");
};

function hook(element, useCapture) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var type;
    if (this === e.target) {
      type = "target (" + (useCapture ? "capture" : "bubbling") + " handler)";
    } else {
      type = useCapture ? "capture" : "bubbling";
    }
    console.log(this.id + ": " + type);
  }, useCapture);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      Click Me
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That gives us the output:

```
outer: capture
middle: capture
inner: target (bubbling handler)
inner: target (capture handler)
inner: DOM0
middle: bubbling
middle: DOM0
outer: bubbling
outer: DOM0
```

**Note:** The order in which the DOM0 handlers are run relative to the `addEventListener(..., ..., false)` handlers is not defined. Some browsers run them before, others after.

Output explained:

1. Capture phase:

   - The event passes through `outer`, so `outer`'s capture handler is run.
   - It passes through `middle`, so `middle`'s capture handler is run.
2. Target phase:

   - The event arrives at `inner`, so all of `inner`'s target handlers run, in the order in which they were attached. So we see `inner: target (bubbling handler)` then `inner: target (capture handler)` because we hoooked the bubbling handler before hooking the capture handler. (I did that to emphasize that the target phase is neither bubbling nor capturing, but its own thing, and fires both capture and bubbling handlers.)
   - The DOM0 handler for `inner` is run (some browsers would do this before the handlers above).
3. Bubbling phase

   - The event bubbles to `middle`, so `middle`'s bubbling handler is run, and then its DOM0 handler (some browsers would fire the DOM0 handler first)
   - The event bubbles to `outer`, to `outer`'s bubbling handler is run, and then its DOM0 handler (again, the order varies by browser).

Comment: Thank you. I found the statement of the second paragraph "If true, ..." here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff943607(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DenisGiffeler: ***Wow*** is that page badly written. Some MSDN content is of fairly low quality, being authored by interns in Redmond. :-)